# How to do pagination of grid by loading a store with local data with totalCount

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

This is my encoded result :

```
{"items":[{"sourceId":"EPH1303270001004","ccy":"EUR","amount":"50.00000"}],"totalCount":1}
```

I am trying to do load the store2 of grid2 using above result as:

```
 var D = Ext.decode(aboveResult);
 grid2.loadData(D.items);
```

Result of: **console.log(D);**

```
Object
    items: Array[1]
    totalCount: 1
__proto__: Object
```

Is it possible to do pagination using above way? Here I am not able to load the totalCount of    store.I am confused with this approach.But my requirement is,that I need to load the data for **store2** using **loadData()**. But facing problem doing pagination.
Please help me resolve this.Any help is appreciated.If my approach is wrong please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `'Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy'` as used in the ExtJS example "sliding-pager" [**here**](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/sliding-pager.js).

[**Ext.toolbar.Paging**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) says:

> Paging can also be accomplished with local data using extensions:
>
> ```
> Ext.ux.data.PagingStore
> Paging Memory Proxy (examples/ux/PagingMemoryProxy.js)
> ```

Full example:

```
var oStore = Ext.create( 'Ext.data.Store', {
            pageSize: 3,
            ...
         } );

oStore.setProxy( {
            type: 'pagingmemory',
            data: arData,
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
         } );

         oStore.load( {
            params: {
               start: 0,
               limit: 3
            } 
         } );
```